# How to use Python imports between scripts in the same folder, imported as part of a package, and run as a stand-alone script within the folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I have been reading through absolute vs relative imports for a long time and nothing has helped me.

Say I have a python module structured like so:

```
└── test_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── script1.py
    ├── script2.py
    └── main.py
```

- `__init__.py` is blank
- `script1.py` has functions
- `script2.py` accesses script1. This can be achieved through `from . import script1`,`import .script1` (relative) or `import script1` (absolute)
- `main.py` is a script that runs a function from script1 on the command line, and therefore includes `if '__name__'==__main__:` followed by some version of `import script1`

I want to be able to import script2 into a python terminal both outside and inside the folder, and run the main.py script on the command line from both outside and inside the folder i.e. `python test_project/main.py`.

Despite a lot of trying, I cannot find any way of writing the import commands such that `import script2` works in all these cases.

For example, if I use `from . import script1` in main and script2 and run `from test_project import script2` in python from outside the folder, it works fine. But if I run `python test_project/main.py` or try to import in python when within the folder, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import script1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I can try to modify the imports to be absolute to fix this. For example making main and script2 have `import script1` rather than being relative. Now running main and importing from a python within the folder is ok, but importing from outside the folder with `from test_project import script2` gives:

```
<ipython-input-1-c3cdbe7a7496> in <module>
----> 1 from test_project import script2
~/python/test_project/script2.py in <module>
----> 1 import script1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script1'
```

Is it, therefore, impossible to write import statements in such a way that these functionalities are possible?